# What machine learning technique can be used for multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, data-mining, forecasting, price, multivariate-testing

I'm trying to predict the price of tomatoes, I've collected a data set that contains the previous tomato price along with which I've also added features that might affect the change in tomato price, for example, wages in agriculture over months, inflation rate over months, rainfall over months. Does this qualify as a multivariate time series? What machine learning technique can be used to solve this problem? The constraint is that there are only 48 data points (4 years *12 months). Also, can the test and train be pulled using Cross Validation ?

Columns in my dataset:

1. Year
2. Month
3. Tomato price
4. Wage
5. Inflation
6. Rainfall
7. Number of festivals in the month

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: This is something you can use in python https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/

Comment: Thanks a million! But can LSTM be applied on 48 rows ??

Comment: Why not? Did you try? 48 rows mean a significant amount.

Comment: @SuraniMatharaarachchi 48 is "significant"? By what definition of significant? It definitely is tiny.

Comment: Thank you sir ! I tired a RNN model on my dataset and I got a good absoulte error! I was skeptical because neural networks are used on large datasets ! @Anony-Mousse

Comment: Thank you Sir for the suggestion @SuraniMatharaarachchi